# Problem with SD card initialization with PIC18F452 using mikroC

Tags: pic, sd

I'm trying to write a text file to an SD card with a PIC18F452 using mikroC. I'm using a mikroC library named Mmc_FAT16 and I formatted the SD card to FAT, but I can't initialize the SD card.

I tried reading the error function and it returns 0xFF which means MMC/SD card was not detected

My code is as follows:

```
void usart_sendstring (char *s);
void usart_sendchar(char chr);
void usart_init(void);
sbit Mmc_Chip_Select at LATB4_bit;
sbit Mmc_Chip_Select_Direction at TRISB4_bit;

unsigned long size;
char character[10];
unsigned char i;
char err;
short fhandle;

void main()
{
    usart_init();
    usart_sendstring("start");
    SPI1_Init_Advanced(_SPI_MASTER_OSC_DIV64, _SPI_DATA_SAMPLE_MIDDLE,_SPI_CLK_IDLE_LOW, _SPI_LOW_2_HIGH);
    err=Mmc_Fat_Init();

    if (err == 0) 
    {
       usart_sendstring("sd card initialized successfully");
    }
    else if (err != 0)
    {
       usart_sendstring("error in initializing sd card");
       usart_sendchar(err);
    }

    Mmc_Fat_Assign("MIKRO007.TXT", 0xA0);
    Mmc_Fat_Append();
    fhandle = Mmc_Fat_Open("MIKRO007.TXT.TXT", FILE_WRITE, 0x01);

    Mmc_Fat_Write("Hello world", 255);
    Mmc_Fat_Reset(&size);
        
    for (i=0; i<11; i++);
    {
       Mmc_Fat_Read(&character[i]);
       usart_sendstring(character);
    }
    Mmc_Fat_Close();
 }

 void usart_init(void)
 {
    TXSTA |= (1<<5);  // Transmit Enable bit
    TXSTA |= (1<<2);  // baudrate generator to high speed
    TRISC |=(1<<7);   // congifure rx and tx
    TRISC &=~(1<<6);
    RCSTA |= (1<<7);  // serial enable bit
    RCSTA |= (1<<4);  // Enabling the reception by setting bit CREN
    SPBRG = 129;      // baudrate 9600
}

void usart_sendchar(char chr)
{
    while (!(TXSTA &(1<<1)));
    TXREG  =chr;
}

void usart_sendstring (char *s)
{
    while (*s)
    {
        usart_sendchar(*s);
        s++;
    }
}
```

I also tried measuring the voltage of the pins; the voltage of the SCK pin shows 0 V.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Is `else if (err = !0)` what you intended to write?

Comment: I meant if err is not equal to 0

Comment: That would be `else if (err != 0)`.

Comment: oh my bad! thanks now it shows FF